# split, map data in two columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, split

I want to split data in two columns from a data frame and construct new columns using this data.

My data frame is,

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame( {"A": ["GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL", "GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL", "GT:DP:RO:QR:AO:QA:GL", "GT:DP:GL", "GT:DP:GL"], "B": ["0/1:71:43:1363:28:806:-71.1191,0,-121.278", "0/1:71:43:1363:28:806:-71.1191,0,-121.278", "0/1:71:43:1363:28:806:-71.1191,0,-121.278", "1/1:49:-103.754,0,-3.51307", "1/1:49:-103.754,0,-3.51307"]} )
```

I want individual columns named `GT, DP, RO, QR, AO, QA, GL` with values from column `B`

I want to produce output as,
[image]

We can split the two columns using `a = df.A.str.split(":", expand = True)`and `b = df.B.str.split(":", expand = True)` to get two individual data frames. These can be merged with `c = pd.merge(a, b, left_index = True, right_index = True)` to get all desired data. But, not in the format as expected.
[image]

Any suggestions ? I think better way can be using `split` on both columns `A` and `B` and then creating a `dict`column  with values from `A` as key and `B` as values. Then this column can be converted to data frame.
Thanks

Comment: definitely a situation where showing us what you've tried could help.  read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @piRSquared hope the edits help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `OrderedDict` to preserve the order after creating a `dict` mapping of the two concerned columns of the dataframe split on the sep "`:`", flattened to a `list`.

Feed this to the dataframe constructor later.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

L = dfc.apply(
    lambda x: OrderedDict(zip(x['A'].split(':'), x['B'].split(':'))), 1).tolist()
pd.DataFrame(L)
```

[image]

Comment: @nilesh It's totally reasonable to import and use `OrderedDict`.  This is a much quicker answer.  I think it's more appropriate as well.

Answer (score 2):

- I'm going to split everything by `':'`.  But I have 2 columns.  If I `stack` first, I get a series in which I can more easily use `str.split`
- I now have a split series in which I can group by `level=0` which is the original index.
- I `zip` and `dict` to get series like structures with the original column `A` as the indices and `B` as the values.
- `unstack` and I'm done.

---

```
gb = dfc.stack().str.split(':').groupby(level=0)
gb.apply(lambda x: dict(zip(*x))).unstack()
```

[image]